# Simple jQuery scrollTo will not work/animate

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, href, jquery-scrollable

I have a fixed header bar with basic navigation like so:

> ```
> <html>
> <head></head>
> <body>
> <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>   <li><a id="aboutme" href="#about-me">About</a></li>
>   <li><a id="workme" href="#work-me">Work</a></li>
>   <li><a id="contactme" href="#contact-me">Contact</a></li>
> </ul>
> ...
> ..
> .
> <div id="about-me">
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

I want these to direct to a section in the same page using the 'linear', 'slow' animation values, but my code isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('aboutme').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($("#about-me"),{duration: 1});
  });
});
```

Do you know where my syntax has gone wrong? And would I need to use the jQuery animatedScroll on github to achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a plugin that would give you a `$.scrollTo` function, or was it just something you for some reason tried ?

Comment: `$('aboutme').click` must be `$('#aboutme').click` ?? Assuming you are using a plugin that explains the other syntax code.

Comment: No plugin being used in this function, but there is one available called 'animatedScroll' on github

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, here's how to animate the scrolling without a plugin ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aboutme').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('body, html').animate({scrollTop : $('#about-me').offset().top}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using this [ScrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin.

In your function first reference well your button, you have:

> $('aboutme')

must be

> $('#aboutme')

Then set the time value with just a `,` like this:

```
$('#aboutme').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.scrollTo($("#about-me"),800);
});
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z43y/1/)**